# Access all files using SF1 and Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files, salesforce1-app

I am trying to create a file upload component which can upload a file (type pdf / doc / docx etc) from my mobile SF1 app.

I am using -

```
<input type="file" class="file" aura:id="file" /><br/>
```

I can make it work when I use the lightning component in Community lightning component. But when I use the same component over quick actions and SF1, it gives option only to upload images or google drive.

Any option by which I can upload normal files on my device like pdf doc etc?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me ..

Comment: Possibly but it is same for iOS and Android or may be just platform limitation. Also found some places where it looks like an platform issue because Android does not support it properly, so in a way Cordova / phonegap does not support it and in turn SF1 which may be built on top of this will fail. Still hopeful there will be some way.